# JQuery .on('Click') only working once, not multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Currently I'm trying to make a Like Button with counter for my website. The issue I'm having, is that I'm not quite versed in javascript and AJAX, and do not know how to correctly write the AJAX Request.

The Ajax request does work, and does add the like (also removal works too) but I have to refresh the page, if I want to click that same like or dislike again. I can't keep clicking to like and unlike. (Hopefully that makes sense).

Here is my Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.post-add-icon').on('click', function(){
        var id_post = $(this).data('id');
            $post = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/handlers/addlike.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'likes': 1,
                'id_post': id_post
            },

            success: function(response){
                $('#likeUpdate-'+id_post).replaceWith(response);


            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // when the user clicks on unlike
    $('.post-add-icon-active').on('click', function(){
        var id_post = $(this).data('id');
        $post = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/handlers/removelike.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'unliked': 1,
                'id_post': id_post
            },
            success: function(response){
                $('#likeUpdate-'+id_post).replaceWith(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is addlike.php

```
require_once("../../config/db.php");
include_once("../classes/user.php");
include_once('../classes/posts/likes.php');
include_once('../classes/posts/comments.php');
include_once('../classes/posts/shares.php');

if(isset($_POST['likes'])) {
  $id_post = $_POST['id_post'];
  $id_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];
  $likeTotal = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM likes where id_post='$id_post'");
  $likeTotalResult = mysqli_num_rows($likeTotal);

  $likeTotalPerUser = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE id_user='$id_user' AND id_post='$id_post'");
    $likeTotalPerUserResult = mysqli_num_rows($likeTotalPerUser); 
    if($likeTotalPerUserResult > 0) {
        $likes = new Likes($conn, $id_user);
        $likes->loadLikes($id_post, $id_user);

        $likesPictures = new Likes($conn, $id_user);
        $likesPictures->loadLikerPictureArray($id_post, $id_user);

        $staticCommentCountDisplay = New Comments($conn, $_SESSION[id_user]);
        $staticCommentCountDisplay->DisplayCommentsTotal($id_post);

        $staticShareCountDisplay = New Shares($conn, $_SESSION[id_user]);
        $staticShareCountDisplay->DisplayShares($id_post);
        exit();
    } else {

mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO likes (id_user, id_post, liked) VALUES ('$id_user', '$id_post', '1')");
        $likes = new Likes($conn, $id_user);
        $likes->loadLikes($id_post, $id_user);

        $likesPictures = new Likes($conn, $id_user);
        $likesPictures->loadLikerPictureArray($id_post, $id_user);

        $staticCommentCountDisplay = New Comments($conn, $_SESSION[id_user]);
        $staticCommentCountDisplay->DisplayCommentsTotal($id_post);

        $staticShareCountDisplay = New Shares($conn, $_SESSION[id_user]);
        $staticShareCountDisplay->DisplayShares($id_post);
    exit();
}                               
}
```

This is the response of booth addlike and remove like.

```
    if(mysqli_num_rows($hasUserLiked) > 0){

        echo $likeEcho = '<div class="post-additional-info inline-items" id="likeUpdate-'. $id_post .'">
                            <span id="likeUpdate'. $id_post .'"><a style="cursor:pointer" class="post-add-icon-active inline-items" id="' .$id_post. '" data-id="' .$id_post. '">
                                <svg class="olymp-heart-icon">
                                    <use xlink:href="svg-icons/sprites/icons.svg#olymp-heart-icon"></use>
                                        </svg>
                                        <span class="likes_count" id="' .$id_post. '">' .$totalLikes. '</span>
                                        </a>
                                        </span>';

                                } else { 

        echo $likeEcho = '<div class="post-additional-info inline-items" id="likeUpdate-' . $id_post . '">
                            <span id="likeUpdate'. $id_post .'"><a style="cursor:pointer" class="post-add-icon inline-items" id="' .$id_post. '" data-id="' .$id_post. '">
                                <svg class="olymp-heart-icon">
                                    <use xlink:href="svg-icons/sprites/icons.svg#olymp-heart-icon"></use>
                                    </svg>
                                    <span class="likes_count" id="' .$id_post. '">' .$totalLikes. '</span>
                                    </a>
                                    </span>';

                                }
                            }
```

And lastly, here is my script toggle that is at the beginning of my post loop.

```
                <script>
                    function toggle<?php echo $row['id_post']; ?>() {
                        var element = document.getElementById("toggleComment<?php echo $row['id_post'];?>");

                        if (element.style.display == "block") 
                             element.style.display = "none";
                        else
                            element.style.display = "block";
                    }
                </script>
```

Hopefully that is enough information. Like I was originally saying, if the user clicks the like button once, it displays the correct corresponding response. But if the user then decides to click that same button again(it's displayed new because of the response), it does nothing. Does the jquery toggle need to reload with the response?

Comment: `$('#likeUpdate-'+id_post).replaceWith(response);` is this removing the ID reference from the DOM so its not finding it on the second time? Edit: Ok I can see the ID is re-added in the response html,

Comment: No from what it looks like, it's still there when I inspect after response.

Comment: You should be able to confirm for us whether this is indeed a problem with the clicking event itself or the AJAX call or the PHP side. This is a lot to chew on unfortunately. For instance - does it work if you replace the AJAX with a simple `alert('test')`? Does it work if you replace the php with just `die('test')`?

Comment: Just tried exactly what you asked. After each response, I put an Alert 1, and an Alert 2. The first click I got a response back, after the reload of the response, I clicked the button again, and absolutely no response.

Comment: Hopefully that made sense

Comment: Not cool creating questions, and deleting them when I take the time to give you a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe lies in fact that you send this:

```
'likes':'1'
```

this means that you always set likes to +1.
You should not send the number of likes at all. You should just send something like 'like', and your backend should do something like

```
previousNumberOfLikes++ // increment by 1.
```

You should never accept this kind of value from frontend, because it can be easily manipulated.

Best,

Edit:

I might be mistaken. You are returning `totalLikes`. This might be the issue. If you always send totalLikes without incrementing it, it will never change. Maybe look into this.

Answer (score 0):

You're generating fresh `post-add-icon`so its not here on `$(document).ready()`, try it without replacing like icon

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to unbind the event, follow the offical jquery  website :
https://api.jquery.com/die/

Comment: `die` unbinds things bound with `live`.. I think you mean [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `document.ready` function only once , not multiple time .
put all functions inside `document.ready` like below :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.post-add-icon').on('click', function(){
        var id_post = $(this).data('id');
            $post = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/handlers/addlike.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'likes': 1,
                'id_post': id_post
            },

            success: function(response){
                $('#likeUpdate-'+id_post).replaceWith(response);


            }
        });
    });


    // when the user clicks on unlike
    $('.post-add-icon-active').on('click', function(){
        var id_post = $(this).data('id');
        $post = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/handlers/removelike.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'unliked': 1,
                'id_post': id_post
            },
            success: function(response){
                $('#likeUpdate-'+id_post).replaceWith(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('body').on('click','.post-add-icon', function(){
    var id_post = $(this).data('id');
        $post = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/handlers/addlike.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'likes': 1,
            'id_post': id_post
        },

        success: function(response){
            $('#likeUpdate-'+id_post).replaceWith(response);


        }
    });
});


// when the user clicks on unlike
$('body').on('click','.post-add-icon-active', function(){
    var id_post = $(this).data('id');
    $post = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/handlers/removelike.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'unliked': 1,
            'id_post': id_post
        },
        success: function(response){
            $('#likeUpdate-'+id_post).replaceWith(response);
        }
    });
});
```

});